# PHP display subcategories of categories in table

Tags: php

I have a table named categories where (id,cat_name,parent_id) is stored.Now I want to display all categories and their subcategories in a row.How should i do that? please help as I am new to PHP.
[Here is my database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8VJf.png)

[and this is how i want to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9BYG.png)

```
<tbody>
<?php
$sql_retrieve = "SELECT categories.cat_id,categories.cat_name,categories.parent_cid,brands.id,brands.cat_id,brands.subcat_id,brands.sub_subcat_id,brands.brand_name,brands.create_date,brands.update_date FROM brands JOIN categories ON brands.cat_id=categories.cat_id ORDER BY brands.cat_id, brands.subcat_id, brands.sub_subcat_id, brands.brand_name";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql_retrieve);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt = 1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $query_fetch)
{
echo'
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>'.$cnt.'</td>
<td>'.htmlspecialchars($query_fetch->cat_name).'</td>';
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_cid = '".$query_fetch->cat_id."'";
$query2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
$query2->execute();
$results2 = $query2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if($query2->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results2 as $query_fetch2)
{
echo'
<td>'.htmlspecialchars($query_fetch2->cat_name).'</td>';
}
}
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you have any code that even reads the data from the table?  At least being able to do that will give you a start.

Comment: @NigelRen Here are my codes